# Calculation difference between Days

Tags: csv, haskell, time

I can't get my head around this. I have the following Code:

```
module Lib
    ( csvFile
    , analyse
    ) where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Calendar
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Item = Item
    { name :: String
    , expire :: Day
    , stock :: Integer
    , price :: Float
    } deriving (Show)


csvFile = endBy line eol
line = sepBy cell (char ';')
cell = quotedCell <|> many (noneOf ";\n\r")

quotedCell =
    do char '"'
       content <- many quotedChar
       char '"' <?> "quote at end of cell"
       return content

quotedChar =
        noneOf "\""
    <|> try (string "\"\"" >> return '"')

eol =   try (string "\n\r")
    <|> try (string "\r\n")
    <|> string "\n"
    <|> string "\r"
    <?> "end of line"

parseDate :: String -> Day
parseDate dateString = parseTimeOrError True defaultTimeLocale "(%Y,%-m,%-d)" dateString :: Day

analyse :: [[String]] -> [Item]
analyse csvData = do
    let items = transform h t
    analyseItems items
        where
           h = head csvData
           t = tail csvData

listToItem :: [String] -> Item
listToItem [] = error "Empty List"
listToItem [n, e, s, p] = do
    let name = n
    let expires = parseDate e
    let stock = read s :: Integer
    let price = read p :: Float
    Item name expires stock price
listToItem _  = error "To few/much Arguments"

transform :: [String] -> [[String]] -> [Item]
transform line [] = do
    let items = []
    let item = listToItem line
    item : items
transform line csvData = do
    let item = listToItem line
    item : (transform h t)
    where
       h = head csvData
       t = tail csvData

analyseItems :: [Item] -> [Item]
analyseItems items = do
    --let sale = getOnSale items
    getExpired (head items) (tail items)

today :: IO Day
today = fmap utctDay getCurrentTime

daysAway :: Day -> IO Integer
daysAway day = fmap (diffDays day) today

getExpired :: item -> [Item] -> [Item]
getExpired item [] = do
    diff <- daysAway (expire item)
    case compare diff 0 of
        LT -> item : []
        GT -> []
        EQ -> []
getExpired item items = do
    diff <- daysAway (expire item)
    case compare diff 0 of
        LT -> item : getExpired h t
        GT -> getExpired h t
        EQ -> getExpired h t
    where
        h = head items
        t = tail items
```

Which I use to read values from a CSV File, where one Value is a Day. I already managed to get these working until I have to compute the difference of today to the day the Item will expire. I don't know how to compute the Day. The Error I get is the following:

```
/home/max/Documents/haskell/Hausaufgabe_02/analysis/src/Lib.hs:85:13: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: [Integer]
        Actual type: IO Integer
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: diff <- daysAway (expire item)
      In the expression:
        do diff <- daysAway (expire item)
           case compare diff 0 of
             LT -> item : []
             GT -> []
             EQ -> []
      In an equation for ‘getExpired’:
          getExpired item []
            = do diff <- daysAway (expire item)
                 case compare diff 0 of
                   LT -> item : ...
                   GT -> ...
                   EQ -> ...
   |
85 |     diff <- daysAway (expire item)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/home/max/Documents/haskell/Hausaufgabe_02/analysis/src/Lib.hs:91:13: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: [Integer]
        Actual type: IO Integer
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: diff <- daysAway (expire item)
      In the expression:
        do diff <- daysAway (expire item)
           case compare diff 0 of
             LT -> item : getExpired h t
             GT -> getExpired h t
             EQ -> getExpired h t
      In an equation for ‘getExpired’:
          getExpired item items
            = do diff <- daysAway (expire item)
                 case compare diff 0 of
                   LT -> item : getExpired h t
                   GT -> getExpired h t
                   EQ -> getExpired h t
            where
                h = head items
                t = tail items
   |
91 |     diff <- daysAway (expire item)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any help is welcome, as I have to finish this homework till Midnight today...

Comment: Don't use `do`... This is used for monadic calculations. Only in *some* limited cases you should use `do`.

Comment: How would I do this without do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake is to use `do` in functions that have no monadic context. It is one of the reasons why [*`do` notation is considered harmful* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Do_notation_considered_harmful). `do` expressions are in fact *syntactical sugar*. The [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) describes how to "*desugar*" these.

For functions like `listToItem :: [String] -> Item`, you should not use `do` notation. This will not work, especially since `Item` is not a [**`Monad`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) type.

We can for example implement `listToItem` as:

```
listToItem :: [String] -> Item
listToItem [] = error "Empty List"
listToItem [n, e, s, p] = Item (read n) (parseDate e) (read s) (read p)
listToItem _  = error "To few/much Arguments"
```

In order to calculate the `daysAway`, it might be better to make this a pure function, and calculate the difference with a `Day` parameter:

```
daysAway :: Day -> Day -> Integer
daysAway = flip diffDays
```

The `analyseItems` then can just [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) the items on the `daysAway`:

```
analyseItems :: Day -> [Item] -> [Item]
analyseItems today = filter ((0 >) . daysAway today . expire)
```

Here we thus can obtain a list of `Item`s that are expired at a given `Day`. We do not need the `getExpired` function here at all, or use recursion to filter.

We can `transform` a list of rows to `Item`s with a [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
transform :: [[String]] -> [Item]
transform = map listToItem
```

Now we can make an `IO Item` to obtain the expired items like:

```
getExpired :: [Item] -> IO [Item]
getExpired items = fmap (flip analyseItems items) today
```

I leave parsing the csv file, processing it through `transform`, and then filtering it with `getExpired` as an exercise.

Comment: Well I got some errors, which I could handle, but this one I can't:

    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Day -> Integer’
                  with actual type ‘Integer’

Which is from

   |
54 | analyseItems today = filter ((0 >) . daysAway today . expire)
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @Biskit1943: sorry, the type of `daysAway` should be `daysAway :: Day -> Day -> Integer`.

Comment: Just one more question, how does this `fmap (flip analyseItems items) today` work? I'd like to be able write another function which takes also a parameter `n` for the max. days which an item can be away from the expired date. Like n = 5 => All items which will expire in 5 Days.

Comment: `today` will return the current day, so by using `fmap` we call `analyzeItems thatday items`, that will than process the list of days. You could preprocess the day, like `fmap (flip analyseItems items . addDays 5)`.