# Apply function to list of custom data structure

Tags: list, haskell

Deriving from my previous Question: [Calculation difference between Days](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56618951/8339179)
I wan't to apply a function to a list of my custom data structure `Item`. The problem is I still do not get it how to handle `IO` proper, so here is my code:

```
data Item = Item
    { name :: String
    , expire :: Day
    , stock :: Integer
    , price :: Float
    } deriving (Show)

totalLoss :: IO [Item] -> Float
totalLoss items = sum $ map loss items

loss :: Item -> Float
loss x = (price x) * fromIntegral (stock x)
```

Let's just say, that I am not able to get just `[Item]` so I have to handle the `IO` proper. But whatever I do I still get these errors:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[IO Item]’
                  with actual type ‘IO [Item]’
    • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘items’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘map loss items’
      In the expression: sum $ map loss items
   |
48 | totalLoss items = sum $ map loss items
   |                                  ^^^^^
```

With `loss :: IO Item -> Float` it's the same error and with `loss :: IO [Item] -> Float` I get an other error.

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[IO [Item]]’
                  with actual type ‘IO [Item]’
    • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘items’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘map loss items’
      In the expression: sum $ map loss items
   |
48 | totalLoss items = sum $ map loss items
   |                                  ^^^^^
```

How on Earth am I supposed to solve this?

Comment: there is no (sensible) way to take a type `IO a` as input and output a non-`IO` type. Your `totalLoss` doesn't involve `IO` however - it just takes a list of `Item`s and outputs a `Float`, so give it an appropriate type signature and it should work fine. (As a general rules, you should never use `IO` unless you have to - that is, when you have to interact with the world outside your program.)

Comment: Well, I have to use IO because of Time calculation and loading a CSV. The list of `Item`s I get is IO [Item] so there is no way around it...

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Your program as a whole might well need to use IO to obtain the data it applies this function to. But the function itself should be kept "pure" (that is, not involving IO) where at all possible. And as I said, you've already written a perfectly good "pure" function in `totalLoss`, of type `[Item] -> Float`, the only reason the compiler doesn't like it is because you gave it the wrong type signature. In another part of your code, you can use the `>>=` operator, or a `do` block, to get a list of `Item`s from an IO action and feed it to this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`totalLoss` is a pure function, so change its type accordingly:

```
totalLoss :: [Item] -> Float
totalLoss items = sum $ map loss items
```

The fundamental issue of this question seems to be that the list of items originate from an impure source (which is a perfectly natural thing).

Write as much of your code as pure functions, and then compose those pure functions with impure input in (or as close as possible to) the `main` function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  items <- ioItems -- :: IO [Item]
  print $ totalLoss items
```

As implied by the comment, `ioItems` has the type `IO [Item]`, but you can compose `totalLoss` with `items` via `do` notation.

If you don't want to rely on `do` notation, you can also compose your functions without that syntactic sugar:

```
main :: IO ()
main = fmap totalLoss ioItems >>= print
```

These two variations of `main` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of `totalLoss` to `[Item] -> Float`, then use `fmap` to apply the function to a value of type `IO [Item]`:

```
totalLoss :: [Item] -> Float
totalLoss items = sum $ map loss items

loss :: Item -> Float
loss x = (price x) * fromIntegral (stock x)

-- fmap totalLoss :: Functor f => f [Item] -> f Float
-- so if you have a value of v :: IO [Item], then
-- fmap totalLoss v :: IO Float
```